# Adding empty array to json object in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Problem Question : 
I am making call to API and it returns the object back. Now I want to add the empty array to this object and use it in my view. How would i achieve this with angular?

// Controller This works as the data was manually

```
$scope.deliveryData = [
            {
                productName: 'ProductA ProductA ProductA', quantity: '20', deliveries: []
            },
            {
                productName: 'Product B', quantity: '10', deliveries: []
            }
        ];
```

// controller This does not work :( how would I add (deliveries:[]) to this ?

```
 $scope.deliveryData; // This will be now populated from API 
     MyService.delivery()
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.deliveryData= data;
            console.log(data) //this data does not contain the empty array, how i append to it?
        })
        .error(function(status,data){
            console.log(status);
            console.log(data);
        })
```

I don't know how to achieve this in angular, even I don't know if I am doing this right way. Please give me any suggestions.

UPDATE 1

```
 .success(function(data){
                $scope.deliveryData = data;
                console.log("Before Change");
                console.log($scope.deliveryData);
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.deliveryData.length; i++) {
                    $scope.deliveryData[i].deliveries = [];
                }
                console.log("After Change");
                console.log($scope.deliveryData);
            })
```

Data coming from API in following format:

```
-Object {delivery: Array[1]}
 --delivery: Array[1]
   ---0:Object
   ----name: "ProductA ProductA ProductA"
   ----quantity: 14
```

Comment: Is `cart` the same as `deliveryData` above?

Comment: @NewDev sorry i was making changes when server went down and did not pick it up. Please see my updated question :)

Comment: Can you give an example of what the deliveryData should look like?

Comment: @NewDev your solution is close, but it is not adding to the $scope.deliveryData instead it is adding to array of object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add `{deliveries: []}` to each product item, here is what you should do:

```
    .success(function(data){
        $scope.deliveryData = data.delivery;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.deliveryData.length; i++) {
            $scope.deliveryData[i].deliveries = [];
        }
    })
```

---

UPDATE

It's basic stuff, there's no way it doesn't work, see it here:

```js
var $scope = {};

$scope.deliveryData = [ // no deliveries here
    {productName: 'ProductA ProductA ProductA', quantity: '20'},
    {productName: 'Product B', quantity: '10'}
];

for (var i = 0; i < $scope.deliveryData.length; i++) {
    $scope.deliveryData[i].deliveries = [];
}

document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML = JSON.stringify($scope, null, '\t');
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: somehow it does not add the array to that object :(. I am printing the object to the console can't see anything

Comment: You're printing `data`, my answer modifies `$scope.deliveryData` which is what you use after you fetch the data.

Comment: no mate i am printing $scope.deliveryData, its not in there

Comment: That's impossible. Can you please show me your current code? (you can add it as an update to the question)

Comment: Please see my question, I might be doing something wrong

Comment: Looks perfect, could you just add the output of the console logs?

Comment: Well, you need to access the `delivery` array inside the `data`, not the `data` object itself, you should've mentioned that. `$scope.deliveryData = data.delivery;` will fix it.

Comment: @Shomz you should check if `deliveries` is undefined before initialization. Or could overwrite real data received from backend.

Comment: @OneWay I just solved the issue, didn't go into optimizing it... However, if `data.delivery` is undefined, `$scope.deliveryData` will be undefined, it will never enter the loop and nothing bad will happen. Bad things might happen if `data` comes undefined, but I assume that won't fire the success handled anyway.

Comment: @OneWay Or you meant the `deliveries` array we're adding after?

Comment: Well, we don't know what happens to the data afterwards, it becomes a guessing game. It's a good tip for the OP, of course, but I'm not sure I should touch my answer further as it directly answer the question (I even had to ask for more question info), right?